# How to troubleshoot an Angular app that doesn't load?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular6

I have an ASP.NET Core/Angular 6 app. The app complies successfully, but then it get's stuck in "Loading...". There's no error in the console. I can't even close the browser tab anymore, so it looks like it crashes or gets stuck in an infinite loop. The only way I can close the browser is by pausing the script execution in the browser, and when I do that the UI loads.

It used to work before. I made some changes. Added login page and routing, and even that used to work, until I don't know what change I made that caused this issue.

Let me know if I can provide any more information that can be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

It looks like I'm having [this same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095017/angular-6-app-zone-js-drainmicrotaskqueue-infinite-loop), and I'm on a MacOS.

Comment: Use your VCS to find the last version that worked fine. The next commit is what introduces the issue. Examine the changes in that commit to find what causes the problem. If it's too large, then try splitting it into smaller changes until you find what introduced the issue.

Comment: That’s what I wanted to avoid. I thought there could be a better way to debug this.

Comment: The looping gives you some clues. I'd check for reactive forms, particularly any that use FormArrays or any recent UI changes that invoked onChange events. Both of those have caused infinite loops for me when done wrong.

Comment: OK, it looks like I'm having this issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095017/angular-6-app-zone-js-drainmicrotaskqueue-infinite-loop

Answer (score 0):

i would start by looking at what is supposed to signify and detect the next state because one of those is failing. you could write statements to the console to see exactly where it's getting stuck. unfortunately, your question problem is way too vague to start guessing at.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue. I had added a logout menu item to the nav-bar, and by mistake I had bound the `onLogout()` method to `[routerLink]` instead of to the `(click)` event. So, changing this

```
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="onLogout()">Log out</a>
</li>
```

with

```
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
  <a class="nav-link" (click)="onLogout()">Log out</a>
</li>
```

fixed the issue. The problem was inside the `onLogout()` I was navigating to the login page, and this was causing an infinite loop.